# New device that's not working under "Additional Drivers"

Tags: drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics

I am new to Ubuntu and am currently working with AMD to have them help me get my GPU driver installed properly.

While clicking around fruitlessly, I revisited the Additional Drivers tab under Software & Updates. There, it shows an entry for a device that is not working (please see attached image).

I distinctly remember that this page did not show any entries. I remember this because I came to this page hoping to see something that will help me install my GPU driver.

Can someone help me get through this? I'm not sure if I should "continue using a manually installed driver" when the computer says the device is not working.

[image: Additional Drivers Screenshot]

Edit: 
My release is 18.04. (18.04.3 LTS)
My GPU is an AMD Radeon RX 5700 (not 5700XT)

Edit 2:
Here is the output from

```
lspci -k| grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display|Network'  

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0014
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
--
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 0b36
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Edit 3:
Told to ignore this so I will. To be fair, I did not notice anything "wrong" with the computer besides the GPU driver thing that AMD is helping me get through.

Comment: guiverc, thank you for your comment. I neither provided my release of Ubuntu nor the GPU I am trying to use because I did not know they mattered. Apologies if the information I'm showing is incomplete, I had to look up how to find the release. Using the "uame -r" command, I got 5.3.0-26-generic. That's not the format you mentioned though so I found another command that got something with that format. Using "lsb_release -a" I got 18.04. The description says Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. As for the GPU, I am trying to use an AMD Radeon RX 5700 (not 5700XT). I hope this is enough information.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, you can edit your own questions to add there, we can help you format it if you have problems - but it's much easier there, and you want the maximum people to read it as possible.

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display|Network'`. Edit your question with the output you receive.

Comment: Ignore this. It is not really a device that isn't working. This utility can be misleading in some cases.